# Is there a way to specify bootclasspath argument with Groovy compiler?

Tags: java, groovy, groovyc

I'm need to compile a Groovy code with a specific bootclasspath. Is there a way to specify the argument with `groovyc`. When I specify it the way I specify with javac, it complains about it being unrecognized.

Comment: Do you want to show the command how it is being invoked and error / stack trace that you get when it fails?

Comment: I'm just using `-Xbootclasspath/p:path/to/file.jar` in both javac and groovyc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `-bootclasspath`, not `Xbootclasspath`. One thing you can try if that doesn't work is this:

`set JAVA_OPTS="-bootclasspath C:\path\here"`

or on Linux

`export JAVA_OPTS="-bootclasspath /path/here"`

Also, if you copied and pasted your example exactly as you're doing it, you are missing a space between classpath and `/p` in that example.

Comment: You mean it's `-bootclasspath` for groovyc?